# How to output a file name based on a file chosen in R

Tags: r

Hi I am performing a task on a text file chosen from file.choose which just separates out the lines and then adds a new number to each separation.

I would like to name the outputted file the same as file.choose but instead of .txt I would like it to be called .fa. So far I have

```
fileConn<-file("outputtbb.txt")
longlist <- readLines(file.choose())
lvls1 <- unique(longlist)
cat(paste0("Sequence>", seq_along(lvls1), "\n", lvls1, collapse="\n"), file=fileConn)
close(fileConn)
```

I know its something to do with changing file=fileConn but cant figure out how to manipulate it and all I get is outputtbb.

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You could seperate the `readLines(file.choose())` to two lines.

```
filename <- file.choose()
longlist <- readLines(filename)
```

You now have file name available as a variable and you can bend it, you can twist it all day long (no reference to iPhone 6 bending intended).

To change endings, assuming no ".txt" appears anywhere else in the file name, this would work

```
x <- "file.txt"
sub(".txt", replacement = ".fa", x = x)
[1] "file.fa"
```